# How to secure communication between two rails (on heroku) applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, heroku

I have two rails applications, hosted on heroku, that need to communicate.

For now, everything is done in a RESTful way, using ActiveResource when it's relevant.

Now, the problem is to secure these communications, to prevent that someone sniff the network and then make some call and has access to informations or make some actions.

How do you do that?

Tx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach would be REST over HTTPS.

Comment: Agreed. Just adding that the Heroku docs have instructions on how to enable SSL.  Currently at http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl

Comment: Https is a good solution, tx. And I will put a basic authentification (on https) to be sure the client is a trusted one.

Answer (score 0):

Realize this is an old question, but have you considered using some sort of messaging or queue?  Redis is one thing that comes to mind.